# Why can't my Perl code implement the reverse function?

Tags: perl

Here is my code named `reverse.pl`

```
#!usr/bin/perl -w
use 5.016;
use strict;

while(my $line=<>)
{
     my @array=();
     push (@array,$line);
     @array=reverse@array;
     say @array;
}
```

Test file named `a.txt`

```
A B C D 
E F G H
I J K L
M N O P
Q R S T
```

My command is `perl reverse.pl a.txt`

Why it can't implement the reverse function?
I want to show the result is:

```
D C B A 
H G F E
```

and so on.

Comment: because your are not split the line and instead you are inserting it as a single string. do this, `print join(',', @array);` how many commas you see?

Comment: why `push`-`reverse` when you can `unshift`?

Comment: @vol7ron: Why use an array at all?

Comment: @KeithThompson: good question - I'm assuming he plans on doing something else with the data.

Comment: @vol7ron: I'm assuming that he (incorrectly) thinks he needs an array in order to reverse each line.

Answer (score 4):

Reverse in a scalar context reverses a scalar.
Reverse in a list context reverses the list, but not each scalar within the list.
You explicitly turn your scalar `$line` into a list with one item and then reverse the order of the items.

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.016;
use strict;

while (my $line=<>) {
    chomp($line);
    say scalar reverse $line;
}
```

If you have an array and want to reverse each element (but not the elements), use `map`:

```
my @array = qw(Alpha Beta Gamma);
@array = map { scalar reverse $_ } @array;
print "@array\n";
```

If you want to do both (reverse each element and the elements themselves), do:

```
@array = map { scalar reverse $_ } reverse @array;
```

or:

```
@array = reverse map { scalar reverse $_ } @array;
```

Comment: You should use `chomp`, not `chop`.

Comment: Yep and probably two of them to deal with Windows line terminators.

Comment: Why a double chomp?  I don't think the double chomp will help on Windows; it removes the line terminator (`$RS` under `use English;`).

Comment: @kjpires: On Windows, Perl automatically removes `\r` from the input line unless you ask it not to with a `binmode` option.  And if you have asked it not to remove `\r` then `chomp` won't do it: it only chomps the trailing `\n` even if you try it twice

Comment: In this case, and probably almost all cases, what you really want is `$line =~ s/\s+\z//;` to remove all trailing whitespace.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: Why do you assume that removing all trailing whitespace is a good idea? If the input line is `"foo   "`, the output should be `"   oof"`.

Comment: @kjpires: Ok, what if you have an old-style MacOS file on UNIX? Or                         an IBM mainframe text file with fixed-length lines? And it's unlikely, but you could legitimately have a `\r` at the end of the line in a UNIX-format text file. Resolving different text file representations should probably be done by a separate tool.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I couldn't agree with you more, but you don't know how many times I get files that have gone from UNIX to Windows via a FTP ASCII transformation.  It drives me nuts!  (Luckly the LF-CR from Mac OS 9 and earlier is more than a decade dead or that might plague me too!)  If you have the luxury of choosing a uniform line terminator (and this guy probably does), I agree that you should it and transform the hopefully-never malformed exceptions outside, but if you don't have the luxury and you could get either at any time, then coding for both will only save you time in the long run.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Trailing spaces *shouldn't* be significant and rarely are. The author of the program should know either way.

Comment: @Borodin: A tool that blithely deletes trailing spaces unless that's *specifically* part of its documented interface is broken. A line reversal program applied to its own output should yield the original input.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I disagree. It is no more *"broken"* than a tool that deletes carriage returns and line feeds without documenting the fact. Text files are for *people* to read, and so significant trailing space is a design error. It is that that should be documented.

Comment: @Borodin: We're writing these comments in Markdown, which has significant trailing spaces. Text isn't *just* for people to read.

Comment: Sinan, [`$line =~ s/\R\z//;`](http://p3rl.org/rebackslash#%5cR) to remove newlines.

Answer (score 2):

When you say:

```
push @array, $line;
```

You're creating an array of one value that's equal to the line.

```
$array[0] = "A B C D";
```

When you say:

```
@array = reverse @array;
```

You are reversing that single member array. The first element becomes the last, and the last element becomes the first, etc.. However, you only have one element, so there's nothing to reverse.

What you want to do is create an array with your line:

```
my @array = split /\s+/, $line;
```

This will create an array with each character being a separate element of the array. For example, your first line:

```
$array[0] = "A";
$array[1] = "B";
$array[2] = "C";
$array[3] = "D";
```

Now, if you use `reverse` on this array, you'll get:

```
$array[0] = "D";
$array[1] = "C";
$array[2] = "B";
$array[3] = "A";
```

Here's the program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

while ( my $line = <> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my @array = split /\s+/, $line;
    say join " ", reverse $line;
}
```

The `join` function takes an array, and joins each element into a single line -- thus rebuilding your line.

By the way, I could have done this:

```
   @array = reverse @array;
   say "@array";    #Quotes are important!
```

This is because Perl will automatically *join* an array with whatever character is in `$"`. This is a Perl variable that is used for joining arrays when that array is placed in quotation marks, and the default value is a single space.

Personally, I rather prefer the `say join " ", reverse $line;`. It's more obvious what is going on, and doesn't depend upon the value of rarely used variables.